# Поиск пути из А в Б в Prolog

Tags: рекурсия, логика, prolog

Всем привет!

У меня такая задача на использование Prolog. Нужно найти связаны ли А и Б и пройти через все возможные шаги на пути от А до Б, но тут нужно использовать предикат с 2 атомами и только такой. Как лучше сделать?

```
можнодобраться(А,Б) :- 
            связана(А,Б); 
            (связана(А,В), связана(В,Б)); 
            (связана(А,В), связана(В,Г), связана(Г,Б).
```

Что-то типа того, только как-то нужно чтобы в месте где (В и Г...проболжались запросы с другими путями пока Г и Б не будет найдено, как-то так, я понимаю, что тут рекурсия, просто я в прологе никогда не работал, а тут задание. Вот и туплю естесственно.

Answer (score 3):

Логика в данном случае довольно проста:

Из *А* можно добраться в *Б* если А связана с Б,
ИЛИ из *А* можно добраться в такое *В*, из которого можно добраться в *Б*.

Это практически дословно записывается так

```
можнодобраться(А,Б) :- 
    связана(А,Б); 
    можнодобраться(А,В), можнодобраться(В,Б).
```